# How find the positive numbers $n$ such that $n!=\overline{1999a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{k}\cdots}$

Tags: number-theory, factorial

**Question:**

> find all the postive integer $n$ such 
>   $$n!=\overline{1999a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{k}\cdots}$$
>   where $a_{i}\in[0,9]$
>   (or mean $n!$ left-most four digits are $1999$)

I think $$n!\approx\dfrac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2n\pi}?$$

I have use computer found $n!<10^8$ does not exist.  So maybe this $n$ does not exist?

Comment: Could you clarify a little?  Is it "find all positive integers $n$ such that the left-most four digits are $1999$" or is it "find any $n$ such that..."?

Comment: Interesting question. What's the down-vote for???

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick solution to this in [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) $($although it depends on floating-point arithmetic$)$:

```
n = log(1:100000, 10)
logf = cumsum(n)
first.four = floor(10^(logf-floor(logf))*1000)
which(first.four == 1999)
```

The output is

```
15998  19796  20030  20678  24284  25809  28019 
28956  30752  31432  33289  38840  51822  52487 
53962  56006  56660  59986  69481  69557  70232 
88184  94462
```

which are the numbers less than $10^5$ whose factorials begin with $1999$.

$($Note that this isn't perfect, because of the floating-point dependence; for example it tells me that the first four digits of $4!$ are $2399$, not $2400.)$

Incidentally, factorials obey [Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law) and so you'd expect that about $\log_{10} 2 - \log_{10} 1.999 \approx$ $\approx 0.00022$  of factorials, in the long run, would start with the digits $1999$.  There are $23$ here.

Answer (score 2):

Using a computer$^*$ we can find that
$$15998! = 1999638128545238518 \dots$$

($^*$) Haskell one-liner:

`find (\(a,xs) -> take 4 (show xs) == "1999") $ zip [0..] (scanl (*) 1 [1..])`

Comment: May I ask how you made it ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Added info to the answer.

Comment: Thanks ! It is quite impressive.